# Google Colab. IPython.display - Audio not working in if statement

Tags: python, audio, google-colaboratory

Just started learning Python. I met a strange behaviour of Audio in `if` statement. It should work, but is not working.

See example here: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Jz6znaj047zrtDK-orp8VN0869xDYnQO?usp=sharing

This code works fine (plays wav file):

```
from IPython.display import Audio

sound_hey = "http://thecyberbuddy.com/sounds/hooray.wav"

Audio(sound_hey, autoplay=True)  # plays ok
```

And this not:

```
from IPython.display import Audio

sound_boo = "http://mrclan.com/fastdl/tfc/sound/boo.wav"

s = 1

if s == 1:
  Audio(sound_boo, autoplay=True)  # dose not play...
```

Answer (score 6):

Here

```py
from IPython.display import Audio, display

sound_boo = "http://mrclan.com/fastdl/tfc/sound/boo.wav"

s = 1

if s == 1:
  display(Audio(sound_boo, autoplay=True))
```